# Single navigation bar in iOS tabbed app

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

I'm doing iPhone tabbed application, but I need to use navigation bar also (just for app title and single icon for Settings in the corner) like twitter did: [link](http://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/styles/large/public/field/image/2013/09/twitter_ios_7_update_iphone_hero.jpg?itok=6XYXwZmn). I have 4 tabs in my app too. I was wondering is there any chance to create only one navigation bar, so when I want to change it, I will change it only in one place?

I was looking at [this](http://maybelost.com/2011/10/tutorial-storyboard-in-xcode-4-2-with-navigation-controller-and-tabbar-controller-part1/) tutorial, but there are two "Navigation Bar" objects. And I would like to have single object that will appear in every tab.

Right now I created tabbed app and manually added navigation bar item into first tab. Then I copied it into others. It works ofc, but I'm not sure about that solution:/

Comment: Each tab should have its own nav controller (if needed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of separate navigation controllers for each tab isn't a bad solution.

Setting up the navigation bar and its items in only one place is also a good idea.  To achieve this, you could always have your view controllers derive from a custom view controller that overrides `navigationItem`.

Comment: Well, I don't have navigation controller like in that tutorial.. I have tabbed view controller and 4 simple view controllers (UIViewController). So 5 windows. 4 controllers connected to tabbed one via "relationship". 

And... Into every view controller from those four I put object named "Navigation Bar". But the thing is, "navigation" bar has nothing to do with navigation in my project:/ It's only app title + refresh icon (right now not even settings as I wrote before).  There is no "back" icon.

Comment: Can we not use single Navigation bar for all tabs? please provide some code, so new comers like me can understand the architecture properly